# Javascript Object abnormality in Angular application refresh/ deep link from address bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular 1.3.15 and UI-Router, hosted on IIS 7.5.

The following code contains setup for the `$stateChangeStart` event. When the app has been loaded from the main link, this code is invoked correctly; when a user accesses a state with a role, there is no issue. When you try to hit a link manually via the address bar or refresh the current page that you are on and the application reloads, the function runs but any property on the `authentication.profile` object is empty. You'll see that I am doing a `console.dir(authentication.profile)` when `$stateChangeStart` first fires off. This shows that there is indeed data there, and methods on the object. But if i try `console.dir(authentication.profile.token)`, it is empty.

I am unsure if this is related to the refresh of the app from a different path or something totally different.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
'use strict';

var serviceId = 'authentication';
angular.module('app').factory(serviceId, 
       ['common', '$localForage', '$injector', authentication]);

angular.module('app').run(['$rootScope','$state', '$stateParams', 
  'authentication', function ($rootScope,$state, $stateParams, authentication) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
        function (e, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        console.dir(authentication.profile);
        if (toState.data.roles.length > 0) {
            console.log('has roles');
            console.dir(authentication.profile.roles());
            if (!authentication.profile.isInAnyRole(toState.data.roles)) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $state.go('home');
            }
        }
    });
}]);
```

Authentication service:

```
function authentication(common, $localForage, $injector) {
    var USERKEY = "utoken";

    var setProfile = function (username, token) {
        profile.username = username;
        profile.token = token;
        localforage.setItem(USERKEY, { 
             'username': username, 
             'token': token 
        })
    };

    var initialize = function () {
        var user = {
            username: "",
            token: "",

            isAuthenticated: function () {
                return this.token;
            },
            isUserInRole : function (role) {
                if (this.token != "") {
                    var decoded = jwt_decode(this.token);
                    return decoded.role.indexOf(role) != -1;
                }
                else return false;

            },
            isInAnyRole: function (roles) {

                for (var i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
                    if (this.isUserInRole(roles[i])) return true;
                }

                return false;
            },
            roles: function(){
                if (this.token != "") {
                    var decoded = jwt_decode(this.token);
                    return decoded.role;
                }
                else return false;
            },
            isTokenExpired: function () {
                var decoded = jwt_decode(this.token);
                if (moment.unix(decoded.exp).isBefore( moment())) {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    return false;
            }
        };



        var localUser = null;
        $localForage.getItem(USERKEY).then(function (data) {
            localUser = data;
            if (localUser) {
                user.username = localUser.username;
                user.token = localUser.token;
                if (user.isTokenExpired())
                    logout();
            }
        });


        return user;
    };

    var logout = function () {
        profile.username = "";
        profile.token = "";
        $localForage.removeItem(USERKEY);
        $injector.get('$state').transitionTo('home');
    };

    var profile = initialize();

    return {
        setProfile: setProfile,
        profile: profile,
        logout: logout
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Which behavior do you expect? When you reload the page or navigate to the URL 'manually' the app starts from scratch. And you never call `authentication.setProfile()`.

To keep the session, once logged in, on reload or manual navigation you have to keep this data for offline usage. You can use cookies or [localStorage service](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage).

Then in your state tracking code you will read the storage/cookies once you detect a missing profile and attempt to restore it from storage/cookie

Comment: authentication.setProfile() is called from another service which handles the oauth endpoint. As i said in my comment earlier, if you look at the authentication.profile object via console.dir as soon as it fires you can see the data there. But if i try any of the properties or methods on it in code, I dont get the expected data

Comment: Where is the code of that service? Where do you read the data for authentication when `authentication.setProfile()` is called?`